# Trouble Installing Backtrack 5 r3

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, backtrack-linux

it's getting really messy and frustrating trying to install backtrack operating system. I have downloaded 3 images. There are:

1. Backtrack 5 r3
2. Backtrack R3 Gnome 32bit
3. Backtrack R3 Gnome 64bit

Am operating with 64 bit windows 8 operating system and i have vmware 7.0.0 workstation installed. What i do is click on new virtual machine specify the location of backtrack image set other things and start the virtual machine. Starts fine. Then i get a menu Backtrack live CD with options from which i chose Backtrack Text- Default boot text mode following a tutorial [this](http://backtracktutorials.com/how-to-install-backtrack-5/)

But am constantly getting the same error message for all 3 images:

```
 The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. You will need to power off or reset virtual machine at this point.
```

Have no idea why this is happening first i thought may be it is because the image is for 32 bit windows and i have 64 bit operating system so i downloaded the 64 bit backtrack r3 image but unfortunately it is showing the same. Help me with this error please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Vmware workstation 9 and the issue would be resolved!